# Десериализация JSON (Newtonsoft.Json). Как игнорировать отсутствие объекта?

Tags: c#, json

Есть JSON:

```
{"response":[{"id":5491,"firstname":"Максим","last":{"time":1471165334}},
{"id":5679,"firstname":"Даша"}]}
```

Использую код:

```
string json = source;
var result = new StringBuilder();
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var count = obj.response.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var currObject = obj.response[i];
    string str = String.Format("{0};{1}", currObject.firstname,currObject.last.time);
    result.AppendLine(str);
}
return result.ToString().Trim();
```

В итоге там, где отсутствует last - валится с ошибкой.
Собственно, вопрос: как можно игнорировать отсутствие этого объекта? То есть если его нет - просто пишем пустоту, есть - забираем значение.

Comment: RootObject  ваш класс? Если да, то в нем не может "не быть" last, а может быть просто null. Тогда last?.time

Comment: Да, RootObject - этой мой класс.

`public class Last
    {
        public int time { get; set; }
    }

public class Response
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public Last last { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Response> response { get; set; }
}`

В самом JSON может не быть last, то есть вообще. Пример JSON есть в первом сообщении.

Comment: Ответ тот же. Я не вижу никакой динамики, Вы десериализуете в конкретный тип, который внутри себя содержит другие конкретные типы (допускаю, ибо исходника RootObject не представлено).Если в json нет last, то он ничего не будет присваивать свойству last и оно по дефолту будет null,  а с этим у нас работает новомодная фича ?.